# considering big upper bounds in algorithm complexity analysis

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I was thinking about complexity analysis of algorithms and I came out with this example: there's a medical center with several doctors; each doctor can visit in slots of an hour every working day of the week.
Now, assuming that we have a collection of doctors and each doctor has a sorted collection of scheduled visits, if we want to find if a particular slot is free with any of the doctor, we can write a very basic algorithm to do that:

```
for (Doctor doc: doctors) {
    for (Visit visit: doc.visits) {
        if (visit.hour == hour && visit.day == day) {
            return false;
        }
        if (visit.day > day) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
return true;
```

While I know that this is not the most efficient approach to solve the problem, I'm wondering about its time complexity; at start I thought about a time complexity of O(n^2) since the number of doctors and visits can grow and the code contains two nested loops and the inner loop contains a couple of constant time operations.

But then I thought that the number of doctors has for sure an upper bound, which is the number of people living in the country of the center (if we consider even foreign doctors, there's still an upper bound, the world population ~7.5 billions); so the time complexity seems to lower to linear O(n), since the inner loop is executed only a constant number of times. In Big-O terms: O(C*N) = O(n) where C is the constant upper bound.

Not satisfied, I also thought that this software will not run the medical center for more than a century, because I'm sure that in that period of time it will be rewritten; so the software will accept visits only till year 2117, which is - assuming 230 working days per year, and 8 slots per day, 184k slots, again an upper bound. If you think that the software can last more than one century, the upper bound becomes the expected life of the sun (about 5 billion years) after which life on earth will disappear. A higher upper bound, but still an upper bound. So the time complexity now seems O(1), since O(C1*C2) = O(1) where C1 is the doctors upper bound and C2 is the visits upper bound.

Is this reasoning correct? In general is correct assuming big numbers as constants while analyzing algorithms complexity?

Comment: "What is the complexity of f(n) assuming n is never larger than some constant" isn't a meaningful question. Complexity necessarily requires consideration of f(n) for arbitrary large n.

Comment: Using your arguments, you could argue that quicksort of an array is O(1) because the largest computer in the world has (say) 64TB ram, which bounds the size of the largest array quicksort can work on.

Comment: @Paul Hankin: that's exactly what I was thinking. So, why talking about asymptotic complexity if computer structure is inherently finite (and so has an upper bound)? What am I missing?

Comment: Complexity analysis uses an abstraction of computing that doesn't correspond exactly with reality. Despite that, it often gives useful information about the efficiency of real programs.

Comment: If you read some of Sedgewick's books, you'll find he tries to model/predict actual runtimes rather than complexities. But it results in harder math, which I guess is why it's not a common technique. See, eg: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hz95qqOdx0

Answer (score 1):

If every doctor has equal number of `visits`, that is , if the following loop

```
for (Visit visit: doc.visits)
```

always runs for a constant number of times, then it does not matter whether it runs **billion** times or it runs **10 or 20** times. As long as it is constant number, the time complexity will always be **O(n), which is linear**

Reason is the definition of **Big O**:

`f(n) = O(g(n))` when we have `f(n) <= cg(n)`, for all `n > n'` and for some constant `c`. So as long as the inner loop runs for a constant amount of time, say **1000000** times. We have `f(n) = 1000000n` and we get:

```
f(n) = 1000000n <= 1000001n, for all n > 0 and c = 1000001
```

and we get **f(n) = O(n)**.